# В чем отлаживать код

Tags: android

Занимаюсь разработкой по под android. Все просто, пишешь и отлаживаешь код в AndroidStudio.
Для смартфонов на android есть кастомный рекавери TWRP, собирается под линуксом с помощью make файлов. Вопрос вот какой. Как обычно пишут такой код и где отлаживают (TWRP).

Answer (score 1):

TWRP [написан на С++](https://github.com/omnirom/android_bootable_recovery/). Соответственно, писать такой код можно в любой IDE, поддерживающей С++ и там же и отлаживать. А судя по [этой теме на XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1943625), скомпилированный код можно в некоторых пределах отлаживать (или как минимум настраивать) прямо в эмуляторе Андроид Студии.